# Angular 4 Error: Unexpected token <

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, angular, typescript

I'm building a web app using visual studio 2015 and angular 4.x
I have followed [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181888/Angular-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-API-Part) tutorial

But i keep getting the error
 Unexpected token <

[image]

my main .ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';



platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**wwwroot structure**

[image: wwwroot structure]

_Layout.cshtml looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('wwwroot').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        map: {
            'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
            '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
            'app': './app',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api'
        },
        packages: {
            'app': {
                main: 'main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },

            '@angular/platform-browser': {
                main: 'bundles/platform-browser.umd.js'
            },

            '@angular/core': {
                main: 'bundles/core.umd.js'
            },

            '@angular/http': {
                main: 'bundles/http.umd.js'
            },

            '@angular/compiler': {
                main: 'bundles/compiler.umd.js'
            },

            '@angular/compiler-cli': {
                main: 'index.js'
            },

            '@angular/router': {
                main: 'bundles/router.umd.js'
            },

            '@angular/upgrade': {
                main: 'bundles/upgrade.umd.js'
            },

            '@angular/forms': {
                main: 'bundles/forms.umd.js'
            },

            '@angular/common': {
                main: 'bundles/common.umd.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },

            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {
                main: 'bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js'
            },

            '@angular/platform-server': {
                main: 'bundles/platform-server.umd.js'
            },

            'rxjs': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },

            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

index.html

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

I'm not able to go any further.
Can anybody guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: On your view page you have extra '<' symbol you have to check once.

Comment: when i click on the error it takes me to the index.html file inside the wwwroot

Comment: And you don't have any transpilation error ?

Comment: So what is in `index.html`?

Comment: You should post your `systemjs.config.js`

Comment: @PierreDuc:Done added the files

Comment: Should there be any index.html at all?.or should the content of app.compoment.html be loaded?

Comment: Change the System import to: `System.import('main.js')`

Comment: Index.html with _Layout.cshtml? Shouldn't you have a index.cshtml with <app-root></app-root> that gets rendered by @RenderBody()?